# How to display preview of application when switching apps in android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So I'm developing an application in Flutter and by default, there is this weird behaviour in which when I press the button to switch to a different app in android, my app displays a black screen while other apps display a preview of the current screen.

I've been trying to find information about this but I haven't found anything. The closest thing are the splash-screens but they are only displayed during the app's load state and it's not what I'm referring to.

Does anyone have an idea of how this is handled/implemented? I don't think it's a bug because someone else must have already complained about it but I don't know if there is a specific term for this particular screen or this action that I'm not aware of.

[image: preview with a black screen instead of content]

Comment: This happens if you use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE` which prevents screenshotting your activity.

Comment: @Pawel Sadly that's not the case. I'm not using `FLAG_SECURE` anywhere in my code.